# Perda de dados na sessão

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo um formulário com passos em Ajax. A ideia é a cada passo pegar o os dados do formulário, jogar um array e armazenar o array na sessão, para que eu possa manipular todos os dados no ultimo passo:

**Ajax formulario1:**

```
$('.next').click(function(){
   $.post({
      url: '/teste_mvc/turma/step1/' ,
      data: $('#step1').serialize(),
      success: function (e){alert(e);}
});
```

**Action step1**

```
public function Step1(){
    session_start();
    $ses = array();
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$p){
        $ses[$k] = $p;
    }
    $_SESSION['step1'] = $ses;
    print_r($_SESSION['step1']);
    exit;
}
```

Até aqui a aplicação funciona como deveria, problema é com o segundo passo em diante:

**Ajax formulario2:**

```
 $('.next').click(function(){
     $.post({
         url: '/teste_mvc/turma/step2/' ,
         data: $('#step2').serialize(),
         success: function (e){alert(e);}
      });
 });
```

**Action step2**

```
 public function Step2(){
    session_start();
    $ses = array();
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$p){
        $ses[$k] = $p;
    }
    $_SESSION['step2'] = $ses;
    print_r($_SESSION['step1']);
    print_r($_SESSION['step2']);
    exit;
}
```

Ao retornar os dados da sessão de volta para o ajax o valor do `$_SESSION['step2']` o PHP consegue recuperar, mas os dados da `$_SESSION['step1']` são perdidos, com o PHP retornando `undefined` pra ela.

Devo estar cometendo um erro bobo, mas estou tentando fazer funcionar aqui e tudo que sei  já foi aplicado.

Comment: Esses foreach para percorrer o array $_POST são escusados, para isso bastava  `$_SESSION['step1'] = $_POST;`

Comment: @Miguel eu já resolvi esse problema, é que criei uma custon mvc pro projeto e estava tendando deixar a sessão global. Bastou chamar a sessão a cada requisição que os dados não se perderam mais

Comment: Este não era o ponto da questão, é só para apontar essa redundancia no seu código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema no código é bastante simples e realmente é uma bobeira, você está reiniciando as sessões, o `session_start()` deve ser utilizado apenas 1 vez. Você pode muito chamá-lo no início do código. Fortemente não recomendo a utilização dele dentro de uma função!

**Solução:** O que você pode estar fazendo e por o `session_start()` fora das funções, iniciando-se apenas uma vez. No começo do código preferencialmente!